# SQL Server; trying to join three tables, aggregate and group results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL...

I am working with the following three tables:

**Table: Campaigns**

```
Campaign SourcePhone  StartDate  EndDate
A         1112223333  20140303   20140309
B         2223334444  20140303   20140309
C         1112223333  20140310   20140316
D         3334445555  20140217   20150217
```

**Table: PhoneMapping (mapping of SourcePhone from Campaigns to Orders table)**

```
SourcePhone TransferToPhone
1112223333  9998887777
1112223333  8887776666
2223334444  7776665555
3334445555  6665554444
3334445555  5554443333
```

**Table: Orders**

```
Date     TransferToPhone Orders
20140304 9998887777      3
20140304 8887776666      4
20140304 6665554444      34
20140305 7776665555      7
20140305 9998887777      5
20140306 9998887777      10
20140306 8887776666      13
20140307 8887776666      7
20140309 7776665555      1
20140311 9998887777      35
20140313 8887776666      8
20140315 9998887777      22
20140305 6665554444      11
```

I've been trying to come up with a query that will join these three tables and provide the results below.  Essentially, I need to come up with a sum of TotalOrders for every campaign, SourcePhone #, Transfer to phone #, and the date range (between StartDate and EndDate for each campaign).  Below are the results that I am expecting a query to provide (I think I did the math right).  Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Expected results:**

```
Campaign    SourcePhone TransferToPhone StartDate   EndDate     TotalOrders
A           1112223333  9998887777      20140303    20140309    18
A           1112223333  8887776666      20140303    20140309    24
B           2223334444  7776665555      20140303    20140309    8
C           1112223333  9998887777      20140310    20140316    57
C           1112223333  8887776666      20140310    20140316    8
D           3334445555  6665554444      20140217    20150217    45
```

Here is what I tried, but it does not group the data based on the date range:

```
SELECT  C.Campaign, C.SourcePhone, PM.TransferToPhone, C.StartDate , C.EndDate, O.TotalOrders
FROM    Campaigns AS C
    INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT SourcePhone, TransferToPhone
           FROM            PhoneMapping
           WHERE        (TransferToPhone IS NOT NULL)) AS PM ON C.SourcePhone = PM.SourcePhone 
           INNER JOIN
             (SELECT        TransferToPhone, SUM(Orders) AS TotalOrders
               FROM            Orders
               WHERE        (Orders IS NOT NULL) 
               Group by TransferToPhone) AS O ON PM.TransferToPhone = O.TransferToPhone

GROUP BY C.Campaign, C.SourcePhone, PM.TransferToPhone, C.StartDate , C.EndDate
```

Comment: MySQL or Microsoft? please fix your tags.  Also please look up JOIN tags.

Comment: Which RDBMS, and aonsider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Also, show us that you've tried something.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The tags were updated and a query I tried to play with was posted.

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you what you need?

```
SELECT  C.Campaign,
        C.SourcePhone,
        P.TransferToPhone,
        C.StartDate,
        C.EndDate,
        SUM(O.TotalOrders)
FROM Campaigns C
  JOIN PhoneMapping P
    ON C.SourcePhone = P.SourcePhone
  JOIN Orders O
    ON O.TransferToPhone = P.TransferToPhone
GROUP BY C.Campaign, C.StartDate, C.EndDate, P.SourcePhone, P.TransferToPhone
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that as a rule all tables should have a unique ID. And other tables should link up on these Keys. So instead of mapping on SourcePhone and TransferPhone here you should be Using something like CampaignID, PhoneMappingID, and OrderID.

Comment: Agreed, that would aid accurately identifying unique records and improve normalization since there would no longer be any need to duplicate SourcePhone and TransferToPhone.

Comment: Not to mention it is much easier for the database to index and thus extends application performance over time as database records grow.

Comment: Sorry, but the above code does not group the results based on the StartDate and EndDate ranges. It groups by TransferToPhone only.

Comment: I understand that it is not ideal.  Is it however possible to write a query against the current DB design to accomplish the task? Thanks again for any help you can provide.